# How to track down an ip address

Tags: network

I am trying to understand network security on my Home network.
I have McAfee Home Network Defense.  It has a home network map.

On the Home Network map is an IP address I am convinced is a spoof.  And, I am convinced it is an intruder and have marked it as such.

I believe this because I have physically inspected every device in my home network to confirm the ip address of each.   I confirmed my wireless printer by turning it off and checking which device went offline.

I have three android phones active and connected.  I have Two PCs identified.  There is one device left on the map.   Also, there is one device in the house that refuses to show up on that network map.

I thought they might be one and the same.   The Device that does not show is a Samsung ChromeBook.   It displays a particular ip address.   This address does not show up on the map when it is connected to the network and is, in fact, "online".

In the map is an ip address that is one number higher than the Samsung ChromeBook.   But I cannot locate the device with that ip address anywhere in my house.

At first I thought this might be an "off by one" error, and that they were the same devices.   This proved out to be false.  Disabling the wifi on the ChromeBook did NOT take the anomalous ip address "offline".   I executed several Network Map refreshes to confirm this.

So the brief description of the problem is this.  One ChromeBook device is on my network but does not show on my network map (which is a little scary), AND I have a device within range of my wireless network that is connected but that I can not identify.

How might I resolve this?

regards

Comment: have you tried to release and renew the IP address in the Chromebook that is able to connect?

Comment: Is there a hostname associated with the rogue IP? Does the network map give you a MAC address for the device? Googling the first 6 digits of the MAC address might give you a manufacturer.

Comment: You could try blacklisting the Mac Address and see who would complain or if anything new would popup :)

Comment: Perform MiTM with cain&abel/other against the offending peer.